# how to remove the Altair yaxis like the picture attached?

Tags: python, visualization, altair

[image]

how to remove the blue part?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',
    color='species'
).configure_axis(
    grid=False
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
```

I have spent a whole afternoon to find a proper syntax for removing it, there are too many parameters and I am totally confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hide the axis by setting `axis=None` in the associated encoding:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y=alt.Y('petalLength', axis=None),
    color='species'
).configure_axis(
    grid=False
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
```

[image]

If you want to hide just the ticks and domain line, you can set the `ticks` and `domain` axis properties to `False`:

```
alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y=alt.Y('petalLength', axis=alt.Axis(ticks=False, domain=False)),
    color='species'
).configure_axis(
    grid=False
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jake, thank you. Do you know how to remain the ynumber rather than removing them all (only tick number, remove the '-' )?